# How to do Composite Button on xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I would like to add 2 labels or 2 photos into the button. I want set vertical options and horizontal options. How can i to do? I am currently working on ios.
It would be better if you tell me ios renderer.

Like this;

[image]

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize a Button via [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). Create your button renderer and add related [BindableProperty](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/). Then you can set the text of the labels in Xaml.

Here's my code as an example:

1. MyButton.cs in PCL, set the BindableProperty here:

   ```
   public class MyButton : Button 
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty LabelOneTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelOneText", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
       public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTwoTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("LabelTwoText", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);


       public string LabelOneText
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(LabelOneTextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(LabelOneTextProperty, value); }
       }

       public string LabelTwoText
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTwoTextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(LabelTwoTextProperty, value); }
       }
   }
   ```
2. MyButtonRenderer.cs in iOS platform, add the labels to MyButton and set their Frames:

   ```
   class MyButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
   {

       UILabel labelOne;
       UILabel labelTwo;

       public override void LayoutSubviews()
       {
           base.LayoutSubviews();
           nfloat height = Control.Frame.Size.Height;
           nfloat width = Control.Frame.Size.Width;

           if (labelOne!=null)
               labelOne.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, width, height / 2);

           if (labelTwo != null)
               labelTwo.Frame = new CGRect(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);

       }
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

           if (Control != null)
           {
               var button = e.NewElement as MyButton;

               labelOne = new UILabel();
               labelOne.Text = button.LabelOneText;
               labelOne.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

               labelTwo = new UILabel();
               labelTwo.Text = button.LabelTwoText;
               labelTwo.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

               this.AddSubview(labelOne);
               this.AddSubview(labelTwo);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set the texts of the button's labels at MainPage.xaml in PCL:

   ```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:MyButton LabelOneText="OneText" LabelTwoText="TwoText" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
   ```

   It runs like this:

   [image]

Also, for adding photos, you just need to replace the UILabels to UIImageViews.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. But i have a problem. I can't set horizontal options and vertical options. And button effect is not visible. Button click event working but effect don't working. How can i set horizontal , vertical options and button's efect visibilty?

Comment: @KadirAlan, "I can't set horizontal options and vertical options"-  you can add the related BindableProperty for them. And set the position by frame or constraint. My code set the frames for the labels to let them at the horizontal and vertical center of the button. You can customize them. The default button effect is for the Title of the Button. There's no title set for this button.

Comment: @KadirAlan,Or you can set custom background image for the different state of the button. `btn.SetBackgroundImage(aImage,UIControlState.Highlighted);` and `btn.SetBackgroundImage(bImage, UIControlState.Normal);`

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Grid, add a button occupying all rows and columns and then add the views that you want (the two labels in this case) with `InputTransparent = true`.

That's it, hope it helps!